How can I get a user's Facebook friends using Laravel Socialite in a test environment?

I'm using Laravel Socialite to handle Facebook authentication in my Laravel application, and I’m working in a test environment only. I have successfully integrated Socialite to allow users to log in with their Facebook accounts. Now, I need to fetch a list of the user's Facebook friends after they authenticate.

I've reviewed the Laravel Socialite documentation and the Facebook Graph API documentation, but I’m unsure how to proceed with obtaining the list of friends.

Facebook Permissions: I’ve made sure to request the user_friends permission during the login process.

API Calls: I’ve attempted to use the Graph API directly to fetch friends but haven't been able to integrate it smoothly with Socialite.


Here’s a snippet of the code I’m using to authenticate users:
public function redirectToProviderFacebook()
    {
       return Socialite::driver('facebook')->scopes(['user_friends'])->redirect();
    }

public function handleProviderCallbackFacebook(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->user();
            $accessToken = $user->token;
            // Get friends
            $response = Http::withToken($accessToken)
                ->get('https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends');

            $friends = $response->json();
            dd($friends);
            $data = User::where`your text`('email', $user->email)->first();
            if (is_null($data)) {
                $users['name'] = $user->name;
                $users['email'] = $user->email;
                $users['password'] = Hash::make('password');
                $data = User::create($users);
            }
            Auth::login($data);
            return redirect('dashboard');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Log the error or return a meaningful message
            Log::error('Facebook OAuth error: ' . $e->getMessage());
            return redirect()->route('login')->with('error', 'Authentication failed.');
        }
    }


How do I use Laravel Socialite to fetch a user’s list of friends from Facebook in a test environment?

Are there any specific settings or configurations needed in the Facebook Developer Console for accessing friends data in a test environment?

Can you provide an example of how to make a request to the Facebook Graph API to get friends data after authentication?


Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

If you are testing with real users that you added as admin/developer/tester, then it should be enough if two users both accept the user_friends permission, for them to show up as friends if you request the friend list of either one. If you are using test users, then you need to "make" them friends via the UI in the app dashboard first.

I’m getting an error with the user_friends scope:
return Socialite::driver('facebook')->scopes(['user_friends'])->redirect();
The error is: Invalid Scopes: user_friends. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present.
Is user_friends deprecated or replaced? What should I use instead? Also, does this require app review, or is there another issue? Any help would be appreciated!

And you did not think that was worth mentioning right from the start? What App Type did you chose, when you created the app?

I apologize for the confusion. The app type I selected is "Consumer". This type supports functionalities like authenticating users and requesting data through Facebook Login. If you need more details or if there's something specific you're referring to, please let me know!

It should be available for that app type, and the permission is not deprecated. What happens when you try to login via Graph API Explorer, and try to grant the permission there? (Make sure to select the correct app first.)
